# How can I get a list of running tasks on a remote Windows 7 computer?

Tags: windows-7, windows, task-manager

I know that I can do Remote Session into a remote computer and then run a task manager on it to get a list of running processes. What I'm curious, if there is a way that can show running tasks on a remote machine without doing a remote session?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `tasklist`, specifically `tasklist /S system`.

Comment: Thanks. Although I can't seem to configure it. I get access denied errors.

Comment: You may have to specify the remote username and password. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc730909.aspx

Comment: That's what I did. It hangs up for a little bit and then gives me "ERROR: Access denied". The same by the way happens if I try `Remote Task Manager` suggested below.

Comment: Found additional steps needed to make `tasklist` work: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/5b54f099-1c81-426f-82a0-22426df5c7b2/how-to-call-tasklist-from-a-workstation-to-workstation-without-connection-to-a-domain-controller?forum=w7itpronetworking

Answer (score 2):

There are few other ways to get list of remote processes: WMI query, wmic tool and PowerShell script.

With PowerShell it becomes really powerful: you can query multiple computers at the same time, filter and sort by processes name.

For example, query computers in an AD domain for list of running processes:
`Get-ADComputer -Filter {OperatingSystem -Like “Windows 10*”} | ForEach-Object {Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Process -Computer $_.Name}`
<sup>(typed as all one line)</sup>

Here is detailed description of the syntax:
https://www.action1.com/kb/list_of_running_processes_on_remote_computer.html

Answer (score 1):

There are a few tool to use:

[pslist](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896682.aspx) to list all processes on a remote PC; see [SS64.com](http://ss64.com/nt/pslist.html) for more information (free, from MS/SysInternals)

[Remote Task Manager](http://www.devicelock.com/rtm/) to "Monitor all running tasks, processes, services and events on remote computers." (shareware, from DeviceLock.com)

[Remote Process Explorer](http://lizardsystems.com/remote-process-explorer/index.php) to "get the list of processes and... manage them... on a local or remote computer." (free for non-commercial use, from System Lizerd)

Check these and other downloads in [VirusTotal](https://www.virustotal.com/); I've not tried the last two.

Answer (score 1):

[ProcInsp](https://github.com/CUSTIS-public/ProcInsp) allows you to monitor running windows processes using web ui. It can show not only processes, but also their threads and stackstraces. I'm ProcInsp's developer, the tool is free for use.

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of programs that can achieve this. for an example, [remote process viewer](http://www.file.net/remote-process-viewer/index.html?ref=pview),[desktop central](https://www.manageengine.com/products/free-windows-tools/download.html),etc. there is a list of them [here](https://www.raymond.cc/blog/remote-process-explorer-normally-cost-75-now-free-for-personal-use/).